# Creating Image from Pixels stored in an array in Python

Tags: python, image

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image


im = Image.open("result_bw.png")
l = []
print im.size
pix = im.load()
for x in range(im.size[0]):
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        l.append(pix[x,y])

img = Image.new('L', (im.size[1],im.size[0] ))
img.putdata(l)
img.save('image.png')
```

The above code reads a **black and white image** and stores the pixel value in a list.

When I am creating a new image from the pixels stored in the list, I get the original image which is **rotated anti-clockwise**.

Why am I getting a rotated image?

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the x and y values you read. Computers write images with an origin in the top-left of a screen, y positive axis pointing down, and x positive axis pointing right. Your implementation assumes an origin at the bottom-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Where there is `putdata`, there is likely also `getdata`. Indeed, you could use

```
l = list(im.getdata())
```

instead of your `for` loops. This would also fix the rotation problem.