# How can I convert a flat RGBA array to a Numpy array to use in OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, blender

Blender returns texture images as a flat array of pixel values (RGBA, each stored as single value in a flat array of size width * height * 4).

How can I transform that into a Numpy array and then load that into an OpenCV image?

I am currently trying this:

```
i = 1

for img in bpy.data.images:
    print(img)
    print(img.name, img.users, img.file_format)
    
    print('load start')
    img_arr = np.array(img.pixels)

    print(img_arr.shape)
    img_arr = img_arr.reshape([ img.size[1], img.size[0], 4 ])
    print(img_arr.shape)

    
    print('load end')
    
    cv2.imwrite('out_cv2_' + str(i)  + '.png', img_arr)
    i = i + 1
```

But I get blank images of the right size.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299863/creating-image-from-pixels-stored-in-an-array-in-python) but for OpenCV in Python.

I am aware that I could save the images to file like this:

```
img.filepath = 'out' + str(i)  + '.png'
img.file_format = 'PNG'
img.save()
```

but what I'm trying to get to is an intermediate step to manipulating the images in OpenCV, which I'd like to do in memory

I've also seen [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221110/fastest-way-copying-from-bgl-buffer-to-numpy-array) but unfortunately it crashes Blender.

Comment: OpenCV images are actually numpy arrays, so phrasing your question as "convert Blender image to numpy array" would be more concise.

Comment: Done as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `dtype` when you create the Numpy array. You can check yours with:

```
print(img_arr.dtype)
```

I don't know what bit-depth you have initially, but you need to have `dtype=np.uint8` or `dtype=np.uint16` if you want to store in a PNG.

I mean:

```
img_arr = np.array(img.pixels, np.uint8)
```

You should then look at your scaling to make sure you have a decent range with some contrast. So if your `dtype` is `np.uint8`, you want `img_arr.max()` to be over say 150 for your brightnesses to be perceptible.